# Can't fire event when I click on Label

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using 7.1.0.GA, nothing happened when I click on Label, So I tried to put it inside a View, the event fire when I click around the Label but dont when I click on the area of Label.

Comment: provide some code snippet as this question is not descriptive in itself.

Comment: share some code.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably don't receive the touch maybe your label or parent have touchEnabled false, or probably you have a view above your label add different background color for each element to find the guilty

Answer (score 0):

Set touchEnabled of your Label to false and then it should work when you click on the View.